# Does a stock Windows XP SP3 install include the Visual C++ 2005 runtime?

Tags: windows-xp, installer, visual-c++

I get the sense that Visual C++ runtimes/redistributables typically are a separate install, but my searching has not yielded me conclusive results. I have an old application that I support that requires the Visual C++ 2005 runtime/redistributable. I am required to support XP SP3. With this in mind, I am wanting to know whether a Windows XP box with SP3 installed would automatically include the Visual C++ 2005 runtime/redistributable (i.e. the msvcr80.dll file). Assuming that this is not automatically included with an XP SP3 install, I am going to need to make the runtime a prerequisite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Assuming that this is not automatically included with an XP SP3 install, I am going to need to make the runtime a prerequisite.

Windows XP does not come with any version of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable installed.  Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 do not come with any version of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable installed.  **It is an optional package that must be installed by the end user.**

If you have an application that requires it then you should install it.  **You must be using Windows XP Service Pack 2 in order to exactly that.**

Source:

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387)

Answer (score 2):

No, XP with SP3 does not come with this runtime installed natively.